# What is this behind the pool?

Tags: plumbing, pool

Just bought this house with a pool and notice some water leaking from this thing. Would anyone know what this is? I have called the pool guys and a plumber who are coming in next week to take a look.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A sump tube perhaps?   Allows ground water to be pumped out from beneath the pool bottom.

Comment: @freeman There is a water leak at a home and the op is asking for help identifying, how could this be any less about home improvement?  I would take a hose and flush out the “pipe” it may be an access point for a fill valve.  With a cover so you don’t step in the hole.

Comment: looks like a tube to hold a sun shade. or to reach down to access a valve.